# Retain <select> value after filtering

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

So here's what my form looks like (with 3 more spans [sub1/sub2/sub3] )

```
<label for="levelSelect">Select Level</label>
  <select id='levelSelect'>
    <option> </option>
    <option value='1'>Primary</option>
    <option value='2'>Lower Secondary</option>
    <option value='3'>Upper Secondary</option>
    <option value='4'>JC</option>
  </select>

<label class='dummySearch'>Subject</label>
<select class='dummySearch' style='width: 150px;'></select>    

<span id='primarySearch'>
  <%= label_tag 'subject_search', 'Subject' %>
  <% subject_array = Subject.all.map { |subject| [subject.name] } %>
  <%= select_tag 'subject_search', options_for_select(subject_array, :selected => params[:subject_search]), :include_blank => true, class:'form-control' %>
 </span>
```

So if its a normal filter when i press submit, the value of whatever is inside of `subject_search` would remain there.

The filter that is passed in usually returns a url like this 
`https://example.com/tutors?utf8=%E2%9C%93&subject_search=&lssubject_search=Chinese&ussubject_search=&jcsubject_search=&fees_search=&commit=Filter`

So by default, my form only has 2 select dropdowns. The first would be the `levelSelect` and the other would be the `dummySearch`. What happens is when someone picks an option under `levelSelect`, the relevant `<select>` would render, replacing the `dummySearch`.

Now the problem i face is that when someone passes in the relevant filters and then submits the form, the display reverts back to the original which is `levelSelect` and `dummySearch` and not what filters were passed in instead.

I would like to state though i were to choose the `levelSelect` after filters have been passed i am able to see the selected value in the 2nd select form. It is retaining the value in the `levelSelect` which i am having difficulties with. Since it is a traditional `<select>` tag and its sole role is to dictate what the 2nd select form will render, i am having trouble retaining the selected value.

I am actually not very familiar with jQuery, but this is what was put together to swop between the various subject searches.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function hideDummy() {
    $('select.dummySearch').hide();
    $('label.dummySearch').hide();
  }
  function showDummy() {
    $('select.dummySearch').show();
    $('label.dummySearch').show();
  }

  function hidePrimary() {
    $('span#primarySearch').hide();
  }

  function showPrimary() {
    $('span#primarySearch').show();
  }

$('select#levelSelect').change(function() {

    var i = $('select#levelSelect').val()

    if (i == 1) {

      hideDummy();
      hideLowerSec();
      hideUppSec();
      hideJC();
      showPrimary();
}
```

I didn't paste the entire JS code but thats the idea and it just repeats itself, with `i == 2` and so on and so forth.

I'm not sure if i'm doing it right and also how do i ensure that my form remains as what was passed in and not resetting back to the default?

Comment: How you submit the parameters? An idear to retain the values is put it in hidden input fields.

Comment: I've added in how the filters are passed in based on the url. Is that sufficient? How do i retain the values with hidden input fields?

Comment: If the page is reloading you need to pass your params to your view and render the modified form. Or you could use ajax request to get the filtered values and replace your current select.

Comment: The params are passed and i can see them. The problem i have is with the tradtional `<select>` html tags since they by themselves play no part in the filter and are only used for rendering the 2nd <select> dropdown list. I am unable to retain the selected value for the first select tag.